# How to measure rendered text in Matlab?

Tags: java, matlab, text, fonts

Is it possible to know text dimensions in Matlab?

For example, is it possible to know the following measures

[image]

**UPDATE**

I need no image processing. I know I can deduce the location of baseline of "g" letter with simple commonly used artificial intelligence :) This is not what I want. I want Matlab give me what it has, namely, the font metrics. If it can't then the answer is "Matlab can't".

**UPDATE 2**

Currently I am trying to do via Java interface like this

```
figure_h=figure;
axes_h = axes('Position', [0, 0, 1, 1], 'Units', 'pixels');

s='g';
x=200;
y=200;

fontName = 'Times New Roman';
fontSize = 48; % will be in points

text('String', s, 'Units', 'pixels', 'Position', [x y], 'FontName', fontName, 'FontUnits', 'points', 'FontSize', fontSize);

% make equivalent Java font
jFont=java.awt.Font(fontName,java.awt.Font.PLAIN,fontSize);

% accessing metrics object
jFrame = get(figure_h,'JavaFrame');
jCanvas = jFrame.getAxisComponent;
jGraphics=jCanvas.getGraphics;
jMetrics=jGraphics.getFontMetrics;

%rectangle('Position', [x, y, jMetrics.charWidth(s), jMetrics.getDescent]);
```

but getting null pointer exception at `getFontMetrics`.

Comment: What kind of input do you have exactly? An image?

Comment: I have (a) a text, (b) a font and (c) a size.

Comment: What units is your size (c) expressed in? What units do you want your measures to be expressed in? Pixels/points/millimetres? Is the text being printed, or displayed on a monitor somehow - in an axis, or a uicontrol, or somewhere else?

Comment: Does not matter. Define yourself. I am seeking measurement functions in Matlab. If you know them for printer - then please give a link to me.

Comment: @SuzanCioc do you have only the font name, or do you have the .ttf file as well?

Comment: I have only font name. Also I can be sure that operating system has this font and Matlab can print this font on figures correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can get an image of the font using

```
fh = figure;
text( 0, 0, 'frog', 'FontName', 'tahoma', 'FontSize', 30 );
axis off;
f = getframe( fh );
bw = rgb2gray(f.cdata)==0;
```

Now you have `bw` as a binary image of the fonts (in this example `tahoma` size 30). You may proceed using `regionprops` (especially `'BoundingBox'` property) to compute the desired measures (in pixels).

Comment: I'm not sure using comparing the gray threshold to zero is going to work if the font is antialiased.

Comment: Note that the solution requires the image processing toolbox.

Comment: @SamRoberts I'm not sure Matlab is very successful in anti-alias rendered fonts... In principle you are right. But I believe this is a valid starting point.

Comment: @Shai, how would you find the baseline location for the letter of "g"? It is impossible (very hard) with image processing.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to get the font metrics, you need to create a dummy Graphics object like a  `TextField`, something like this

```
fontName = 'Times New Roman';
fontSize = 48; % will be in points

jText = java.awt.TextField('');
jFont = java.awt.Font(fontName, java.awt.Font.PLAIN, fontSize);
jMetrics = jText.getFontMetrics(jFont);
```

Comment: But these will be Java's metrics. I am afraid they may do not coincide with Matlab's. So, I would like to use mostly Matlab's objects...